# Kubernetes adhoc command scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am a beginner in kubernetes and have just started playing around with it. I have a use case to run commands that I take in through a UI(can be a server running inside or outside the cluster) in the kubernetes cluster. Let's say the commands are python scripts like HelloWorld.py etc. When I enter the command the server should launch a container which runs the command and exits. How do I go about this in Kubernetes? What should the scheduler look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the training classes on katacoda.com as follows.

- https://learn.openshift.com/
- https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes

It's interactive handson, so it's interesting and easy to make sense of OpenShift and Kubernetes.

I hope it help you. ;)